# How to escape $ in SSDT Project

Tags: javascript, sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I am working on some legacy code and trying to get everything under control.

I have some stored procedure that contains javascript. Something like

```
SET @result = @result + '<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {'
```

I have created a SSDT project to keep track of all my database objects. However if I try and publish it SQLCMD will throw a fit as it is getting confused between javascript and its [$(DatabaseName)] syntax.

Is it possible to escape my $ so SQLCMD will correctly parse my SQL code?

Comment: replacing the $ with `' + CHAR(36) + '` might help

Comment: Brilliant that appears to work

Comment: You can normally disable variable substitution in SQLCMD by passing the `-x` switch, but you might not have that option when deploying from SSDT.